# about mysql high-availability

Tags: mysql, high-availability

I read some article about how to implement high-availability solution,the use Heartbeat to check the master mysql is broken,if it broken then switch to the backup server,

one question is when the master server broken,the backup server work on ,how the backup server get the master server 's pre-data

another question is maybe sometimes the master server is not broken,but the mysql service is broken,in this situation is Heartbeat still will switch to the backup server?

Answer (score 3):

What you usually want to do is setup a master-master configuration, but generally only use one master. That was each master also acts as a slave to the other master. In theory, you can modify records in either one and they will keep in sync. In practice, I wouldn't do heavy updates on both servers at once.

My current setup is a master-master configuration, with each master also having a slave off of it. Then you can "failover" to the secondary master/slave and "fail back" when needed. I actually do this if I have database modifications that will take a while.